# Not able to read file using relative path

Tags: java, io, java-io

I don't know what is wrong but I am getting noSuchFileException.The path is right I am able to access it though cmd.

```
Path file = Paths.get("../resources/input.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 1 dot? Unless you mean, the parent directory of the current directory? Can you include the fully qualified path as well as the path of the current working directory?

Comment: you are a life saviour. Thank you :)

Comment: Double dot goes one folder back to the current directory where as single dot refers to the current working directory

Comment: Try also `"resources/input.txt"`

Comment: Java don't support relative paths.

Comment: @Panther Rubbish. Java supports what the operating system supports.

Comment: @Panther what? Of course it does.

Comment: Ohh I thought for file operation, it needs full path. Good my misconception is cleared

Comment: @Panther Where in earth did you get such an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the filename, you're trying to read a resource. A resource is not a file. It is, conceptually at least, packaged inside a JAR or WAR or EAR file. You should use `Class.getResource()` and friends. In this case probably `getResourceAsStream()` is what you need, without the `..`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to formalize it:

Imagine a directory structure of: `/foo/bar/example/test/file.txt`

And a working directory of `/foo/bar/example/`

And a username of `bob`

---

**. (dot)** - Refers to the current working directory (e.g. `/foo/bar/example/` in this case).

**.. (dot dot)** - Refers to the parent directory (e.g. `/foo/bar/` in this case).

**~ (tilde)** [Unix-like only/shell only] - Refers to the user's home directory (e.g. `/home/bob/`)

Directly starting a directory name **without** the preceding slash (e.g. `test/file.txt`) is **equivalent** to using the single dot (i.e. paths are resolved relative to the current working directory).

Directly starting a directory name **with** the preceding slash (e.g. `/test/file.txt`) and you are now specifying an absolute path (on Unix) from root (or, in the case of Windows, from the drive the working directory resides in).

---

A special case exists where . (dot) and .. (dot dot) refer to the same directory, **if and only if** the current working directory is at root `/` ("absolute" root or a chroot jail, either way). The equivalent in windows is at a drive root (e.g. `C:\`).

Comment: Note that the tilde is only valid in the shell; you can't use that in a `Path`!

Comment: @fge Oops, forgot about that. Fixed.

Comment: Should probably note that this is system-dependent, and this is describing the Unix filesystem semantics. On Windows, paths starting with `/` or `\\` are relative, and are resolved relative to the current drive letter.

Comment: @AndrewJanke As far as I know, except for ~ which I've explained, everything else that I've mentioned is transferable across both Unix and Windows, especially when used inside java (the context of the original question). Only the examples are specific to a Unix filesystem. I've added a small denotation to explain "root" handling differences in Windows and Unix.

Comment: I think it's still not quite correct to say that paths starting with `/` (but not `//`) are absolute on Windows. `File.isAbsolute()` will return false, so logic that depends on that (or on cwd staying the same) may behave differently. An "absolute" path is one that does not depend at all on the current working directory.

Comment: @AndrewJanke Hmm... I guess so. I added more clarification to the segment discussing preceding forward slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to check the path taken by the BufferedReader through `file.toAbsolutePath().normalize()` to see the resulting path without redundant elements